# Do I save on server & client load if I don't return any data from a javascript to Node.js fetch call?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch, response

In many case I don't have any use for any returned data from a fetch call dealing with some db operations.

Will I save on the server load by not returning any data and will I save on the client load by not calling for any response?

Is there any best practice reason to advise against not returning anything?

Cheers.

Comment: rsimple status code on the server side tellling if operation was successful should suffice, you said you are using fetch, then `fetch(url, options).then(res => {if (res.ok) {return res;} else {throw MyCustomError(res.statusText);}})`

Answer (score 0):

You must return a response from your server, or that thread would simply remain open.

You do not need to return a response body back and can simply return a 204 status code indicating "No Content."  It would be worthwhile to read up (even if briefly) on [REST Protocol](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/).

Comment: `thread would simply remain open` this isn't strictly true.. you can fire off async (xhr default) and it will return straight away, but no callback (the `then()` you are refering to above) for the later timeout, also, javascript is single threaded so I have a few issues wth the phrasing.. I do agree, you *should* return a status code, but must is not strictly a requirement by the standard.